# Обработка нескольких слушателей

Tags: java, android

У меня есть два поля EditText и 4 кнопки

Я осуществил проверку на пустоту полей EditText в одном слушателе, можно ли как-то реализовать одну проверку сразу для всех кнопок

```
subtractButton.setOnClickListener(l -> {
        if (value1.getText().toString().isEmpty() || value2.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Введите сначала значения", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            resultView.setText("ERROR");
            return;
        }
        Float v1 = Float.parseFloat(value1.getEditableText().toString());
        Float v2 = Float.parseFloat(value2.getEditableText().toString());
        Float result = v1 - v2;
        resultView.setText(result.toString());
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

да конечно,так можно сделать.

Самый простой вариант создать метод, в котором будет проверяться пустоты нескольких EditText.

```
private boolean isBlank(EditText value1,EditText value2){
return value1.getText().toString().isEmpty()||value2.getText().toString().isEmpty();}
```

В итоге у вас получится следующая проверка в каждой кнопке:

```
subtractButton.setOnClickListener(l -> {
    if (isBlank(value1,value2) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Введите сначала значения", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        resultView.setText("ERROR");
    }else{
    Float v1 = Float.parseFloat(value1.getEditableText().toString());
    Float v2 = Float.parseFloat(value2.getEditableText().toString());
    Float result = v1 - v2;
    resultView.setText(result.toString());}});
```